# How do I discover which classpath entry provided a class?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classloader

I am loading several different classes from several different .jars from a custom class loader in Java. I create a custom `URLClassLoader`, add several .jars to it and pass it on to a `ServiceLoader` to find the classes I want.

My question is: given a class, is there a way to discover which .jar it was loaded from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call findResource on Classloader, and parse the URL that you get to figure out where it is coming from.

Comment: This worked for me using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().findResource("MyClass.class")`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The following snippet should work:

```
obj.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()
```

Note that you should add checks for null when calling getProtectionDomain or getCodeSource and handle appropriately in any production code. (It depends on the class loader, security, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the parameter

```
-verbose:class
```

when running your jar/class using **java** and it will give you a full rundown of the classes it loads and their origin, e.g:

```
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/jsse.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/jce.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/charsets.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

That should give you all you need to know to find the class/jar you want.

Comment: Oh, no, I don't want to track down issues. I actually want to find where the .jar is so I can do stuff relative to it's path during runtime.

Comment: Ok, well your issue is the location of the jar I guess.  Anyways, it should give you the exact path of the JAR you want regardless...

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

If I use your -verbose method it will send that info to the stdout, correct? I needed it inside the code during runtime to perform file operations relative to its path. My code needs that information, not me :)